# How do I set up FirePHP version 1.0?

Tags: firephp

I love FirePHP and I've been using it for a while, but they've put out this massive upgrade and I'm completely flummoxed trying to get it to work. I think I'm copying the "Quick Start" code (kind of guessing at whatever changes are necessary for my server configuration), but for some reason, FirePHP's "primary" function, `FirePHP::to()` isn't doing anything. Can anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<?php

define('INSIGHT_IPS', '*');
define('INSIGHT_AUTHKEYS', '290AA9215205F24E5104F48D61B60FFC');
define('INSIGHT_PATHS', __DIR__);
define('INSIGHT_SERVER_PATH', '/doc_root/hello_firephp2.php');

set_include_path(get_include_path . ":/home8/jayharri/php/FirePHP/lib");  // path to FirePHP library

require_once('FirePHP/Init.php');

$inpector = FirePHP::to('page');
var_dump($inspector);
$console = $inspector->console();
$console->log('hello firephp');

?>
```

Output:
NULL
Fatal error: Call to a member function console() on a non-object in /home8/jayharri/public_html/if/doc_root/hello_firephp2.php on line 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inspector variable is spelled wrong where you are assigning it and you are missing a bracket when getting the include path.

Try the following:

```
define('INSIGHT_IPS', '*');
define('INSIGHT_AUTHKEYS', '290AA9215205F24E5104F48D61B60FFC');
define('INSIGHT_PATHS', __DIR__);
define('INSIGHT_SERVER_PATH', '/doc_root/hello_firephp2.php');

set_include_path(get_include_path() . ":/home8/jayharri/php/FirePHP/lib");

require_once('FirePHP/Init.php');

$inspector = FirePHP::to('page');
$console = $inspector->console();
$console->log('hello firephp');
```

Also, according to the `INSIGHT_SERVER_PATH` constant make sure you have a script with *FirePHP* installed at:

```
http:://<hostname>/doc_root/hello_firephp2.php
```